# How to extract a string from url starting and ending with specific letters

Tags: string, web-scraping

I am doing web-scraping, and my task is, given list of movie name, find some data (IMDBid, cast etc.) about it from imdb website.

So first i did a google search "*IMDB Movie_Name*" and try to scrap google search result to get URL to goto imdb movie title page.

```
url = 'https://www.google.com/search?q=IMDB+title+taare+zameen+par'
headers = {'Accept-Language': 'en-US, en;q=0.5'}
page = get(url, headers = headers)

soup = BeautifulSoup(page.text, 'html.parser')
my = soup.find_all('a', attrs={'href': re.compile("https://www.imdb.com/title/")})
for i in my:
    print(i.get('href'))
```

The result I am getting is like:

```
/url?q=https://www.imdb.com/title/tt0986264/&sa=U&ved=2ahUKEwitxIKpj4f4AhUoppUCHfNjB3MQtwJ6BAgEEAI&usg=AOvVaw3zzfaZDFa8tmhGcIRS7_sV
```

My question is how to get a part that is "*[https://www.imdb.com/title/tt0986264/*"](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt0986264/*%22)?

but the logic used should be :
if:

1. string start from "https://www.imdb.com/title/tt"
2. and string ends with "/"
   then return me that sub-string.

Answer (score 0):

There is two way,

- REGEX (https://regex101.com/) all languages supports regex ( ie : php preg_match, .net ( new Regex("...") regex.Match.. , js Regex match search etc  )
- Exploding ( splitting ) string ( for your case "**/**" or "**https://..../.../**" etc ) and take the part of what you need